Order of $\mathbb F _p [x] / (f)$.
I could use some help with the following exercise:

Find the number of reducible monic polynomials of degree $2$ over $\mathbb F_p$. Show this implies that for every prime $p$ there exists a field of order $p^2$.

I found the number of reducible polynomials of degree $2$ is $\frac{p(p+1)}{2}$ since a reducible polynomial of degree $2$ can be written as the product $(x-a)(x-b)$ for $a,b\in \mathbb F_p$.
Since there are $p^2$ polynomials of degree $2$ over $\mathbb F_p$, there are $\frac{p^2-p}{2}$ irreducible polynomials of degree $2$ over $\mathbb F_p$. We can choose an irreducible polynomial $f$ as such, and so $\mathbb F_p / (f)$ is a field (since $(f)$ is a maximal ideal because $f$ is irreducible). But why does $\mathbb F_p / (f)$ have $p^2$ elements?

In general, if $\deg(f)=n$ then $\mathbb{F_p}[x]/(f)$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F_p}$ of dimension $n$. Indeed, show that $1+(f), x+(f),...,x^{n-1}+(f)$ is a basis. (by the way, this is true over any field, not just $\mathbb{F_p}$) In particular, the cardinality of $\mathbb{F_p}[x]/(f)$ will be $p^n$.

Division with remainder. Every element $g$ of $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ can be written as $g=fh+r$, with $r$ of degree strictly smaller than $\deg(f)=2$.

In your computations, since they didn't specify monic, you should count $c(x-a)(x-b)$, with $c\neq0$.

@ameg Oh they did specify monic, I'll edit it in, thank you!
